# Reverse scroll direction on Awesome WM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awesome-wm

I cannot seem to find out how to set the mouse scroll direction in Awesome. I would like to set it to the natural direction (like OS X)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change Xorg's settings, try this:

```
echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12" >> ~/.Xmodmap
```

then log out and log in.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I did not think of doing it at the X level.

Answer (score 0):

Go into system preferences, click on the Warcom Tablet icon at the bottom of the screen. Under tool - press Touch, change scroll to "standard"